# Rejected for having 4 days less experience than a year

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, human-resources, rejection

I recently got rejected from an opportunity just because I have experience 4 days less than a year. The company requires minimum experience of 12 months. In my resume I have put dates in front of experience section with only month and the year. I haven't mention exact joining date ( as I was not aware about a company can be really fussy about few days experience ). P.S. I haven't lied about anything, I just didn't mention the full details.

I have completed  the technical interview and they offered me the place on the same day. When they verified my documents. They found i have less than a year experience i.e. 4 days less than a year. They said it is a company's policy.

I am surprised by the situation as the company is not considering my skills and ability to do the work and clearing the technical interview rather they are declining me for such a small reason.

My worry is, would it be any other reason for declining my application as this sound too lame to me and the company doesn't want to tell me the main reason. Shall I approach HR once again and ask them to negotiate?

Comment: I think your suspicion is correct. The real reason for the rejection was something that was too subjective or too awkward for them to state directly. Being 4 days shy of a year is unbelievably persnickety as a justification, but I doubt that you will ever get the true reason from them. Just move on and perhaps try to find out what the problem is by consulting with a trusted mentor or friend.

Comment: [How do I properly answer a rejection email?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/how-do-i-properly-answer-a-rejection-email)

Comment: I agree with @teego1967 that there's probably another reason for the rejection. However, if it really did come down to a matter of 4 days, that level of pedantry may signal other potential issues with the company that you've now avoided.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere ofrthey have some really poor HR "jobsworth" who probably should not be working in HR at all

Comment: Some people are thinking it is a duplicate post as the answer is mentioned in the above suggested threads. Just want to clarify it is not about "overcoming  year for experience". I was rejected with a margin of 4 days to complete a one year of experience. If it was not a huge difference in fulfilling the requirement if so, they probably didn't took my interview at first place and selected me. They rejected me after seeing the official dates from employment letter.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere ah sorry its maybe a uk term a jobsworth is  "an official who upholds petty rules even at the expense of humanity or common sense."

Comment: Whenever I encounter austere and bureaucratic requirements, I typically find that the reason relating to them is government related. Is there a chance that this position could have legal/contractual requirements for the position to which you applied?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Forget about it and move on. They have already given you a reason for rejection. While I agree with you 100% that the reason is lame, pestering them to tell you the "real" reason is highly unlikely to bear fruit and would just be further waste of your time.

Moreover, as alroc says in the comment, if that *is* the real reason for rejection, you might have dodged a bullet here. If a company is so pedantic about the work experience, I wouldn't be surprised if they deduct a full day's salary because the employee put in 7h 59m of work instead of 8h, or took a lunch break for 30m 21s instead of 30m, and so on.

Comment: and put an anonymous comment on glass door

Comment: Recently I had a word with HR and I have tried to probe if there is any other reason. I have highlight the fact again that I have cleared the interview and your technical team has selected me. Was there any other reason of rejecting me? The 4 days of experience scenario seems to me unjustifiable. He said it was the company's and stakeholder's policy not to entertain less than 12 month experience and they are not willing to waive even 1 day.