# Company blacklist request

Tags: interviewing

I have worked for a very big company a while back.

Since then I have done few interviews that didn't proceed and each time not a single explanation on even feedback email from the employer.

So starting to wonder if I've been black listed in some way..

Can I can request a confirmation to the HRs (or anyone else) of the company?

Comment: [The simplest explanation is usually the correct one.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) There being some big conspiracy that involves a bunch of companies interviewing you with no intention to hire is far from a simple explanation, and if that were true, they probably also wouldn't tell you about it. You doing or saying something that leads to that decision is a much simpler explanation.

Comment: [How can I ask my interviewers for feedback following an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/662) [How do I properly answer a rejection email?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/5750)

Comment: Have you explicitly asked for feedback after rejection? Most places don't automatically include feedback in their rejection. Some places may provide feedback on request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and each time not a single explanation on even feedback email from the employer

Welcome to the world of interviews, it's normal not to get specific feedback these days.

I would say you need help with interviews, and forget about "blacklists".

It is unlikely you are being blacklisted (I would suggest you would know the reason why if you were).  If that was the case, two scenarios would happen:

- you wouldn't get interviews at all
- you would fail at the background check/references part.

The first would imply employers were colluding on hire info, unless your industry is particularly close knit this doesn't happen.

Second is a more likely possibility, the employer is badmouthing you, but it's not what you describe, you only get an interview so I don't think this is happening.

You need to sell yourself at interviews, my guess on your comment on wasting your time suggests you are coming across as nervous or disinterested.  Work at things like that.  You obviously have the skills as you get the interviews.

And get over the paranoia, there is no conspiracy against you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Try to be short in my question and you're right, the second is most likely the case, ie. not good internal referral by someone, though thought that after so much time outside it won't hit me anymore

Comment: @Goul or maybe there is http://www.breitbart.com/tech/2017/08/07/revealed-inside-googles-sjw-cabal-blacklists/

Answer (score 10):

Do you think a company will invite you for an interview if you do not have a chance?

It costs them money. 3-4 Peoples time for the interview, follow up meetings, reviewing CV. Perhaps a test or two.

So why do they not give an explanation. They do not have to and also it may lead to legal problems or hassle.

So just chalk it up to experience. Perhaps try to get somebody to do some test interviews.

Where I live the job centre will do this for you. Perhaps this is the same where you live

Comment: thanks, definitely making sense. though in the company where I work, I am pretty sure that resumes are not filtered by HRs before we interview and that we never consider the time/money it takes us to interview..

Comment: It might not get filtered by HR. It would get filtered by the people that will potentially interview

Comment: Thanks. See my comment in the 3rd feedback. No issue with interviews, they most of the time go very well

Answer (score 4):

> Can I can request a confirmation to the HRs (or anyone else) of the
>   company? My goal is to not waste my time interviewing if not even
>   having the chance to make it.

You can ask HR anything you like.

But you'll almost certainly be wasting your time by asking.

If you were truly on a blacklist (highly unlikely), you would never get an interview in the first place. Thus, your time would never be wasted.

Look for some other reason why your interviews aren't successful. It's exceedingly unlikely to be a black list.

Comment: The end comment of my question was not good, you're right, removed it. I'm generally successful in interviews, see my other comments for explanations